# What is the best design pattern to register data "chunks"?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, serialization

I have a library which can save/load on disk "chunks" which are POD structs with constant size and unique static CHUNK_ID field. So load looks somethink like this.

```
void Load(int docId, char* ptr, int type, size_t& size)...
```

If you want to add new chunk you just add struct with new CHUNK_ID and use Save Load functions to it.

What I want is to force all "chunks" to have functions like PrintHumanReadable, CompareThisTypeOfChunk etc(Ideally program should not compile without such functions). Also I want to mark/register/enumerate all chunk-structs.

I have a few ideas but all of them have problems.

1. Create base class with pure virtual functions PrintHumanReadable, CompareThisTypeOfChunk.
   Problem:breaks pod type and requires library rewriting.
2. Implement factory which creates chunk struct from CHUNK_ID. Problem: compiles when I add new chunk without required functions.

Could you recomend elegant design solution for my problem?

Comment: Are these POD structures allowed to contain pointers?

Comment: Being POD or not doesn't really help you with serialization, since you have to serialize member by member anyway. So why not add a virtual interface that forces your clients to provide the necessary functions?

Comment: Ok, i didn't mention. It is not just pod structs, but also known size structs. So, no need to write special serialization.

Comment: In an imperfect world, even two constraints can make a problem unsolvable. I believe with your constraints it cannot be solved without some compiler modification.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a simple code generator.  You can use something like Mako or Cheetah (both Python libraries).  Make a text file containing all the class names, then have the generator build the factory method and a series of methods which aren't really used but which refer to the desired methods in all the classes.  This will also make it straightforward to enumerate the classes (again, using generated code).

Comment: Code generator could be a good solution. I also thought about it. I am not sure that I can call it "elegant", but if nobody give an alternative I am going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The proper design pattern for this is called "use [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)". It's really the best tool for writing objects to a format and then reading them back later. It can write in text, binary, and even XML formats (and others if you write a proper stream for them). It's can be non-intrusive, so you don't need to modify the objects to serialize them. And so forth.

Once you're using the proper tool for this job, you can then use whatever class hierarchy or other method you like to ensure that the proper functions for an object exist.

If you can't/won't use Boost.Serialization, then you're pretty much stuck with a runtime solution. And since the solution is runtime rather than compile time, there's no way to ensure at compile time that any particular chunk ID has the requisite functions.

Comment: As I mention in question I already have a searilization library, which is used in a number of tools. Also I have large databases in such format. So rewriting library and format changing is rather expensive.

Comment: @ton4eg: But it's not a very good one (in terms of what it can handle. Perhaps you're valuing other qualities). Otherwise, you wouldn't be having the problem you're having. Most serialization libraries can handle what you're doing. Unless you implement serious serialization features in the library (ie: not just blasting structs to a file), or use a better serialization lib, your problem simply cannot be solved. Your serialization library is runtime based, and therefore there isn't a way to verify it at compile-time.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, but it legacy system which hard to change. And I try to understand how to improve it without changing.